# How to use interrupts with x86-64 assembly (AT&T syntax) from Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, interrupt, gnu

I would like to:

- handle mouse events
  (int $0x33)
- clear the console
  (int $0x10)

I read that I can not use interrupt calls from Linux.
Is there another way to do it if I want to keep using Linux?

(I run Linux on emulator (VirtualBox), I am not sure if it matters.)

Edit:
ncurses might be good.
Is this the way to use it (for a simple print)?

```
call initscr
movq $msg1, %rdi
call printw
call refresh
call getch
call endwin
```

Comment: The answer to this question depends a lot on what you want to do.  There is no  “console” on a Linux system and neither is there a single mouse.  To help you find an answer that is useful for you, please tell me: are you writing an application for use in a terminal or an X11 (graphical) application or something else?

Comment: For use in a terminal

Comment: Int 33h is a DOS thing, int 10h is real-mode BIOS.

Comment: That's nice!  That's actually the easiest case.  My recommendation is to use the libcurses, but you can also do it manually.  It's a bit tedious to do it manually though as you have to parse ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: So basically, the terminal speaks ANSI escape sequences (like DOS with ansi.sys) which can be used to clear the screen and to receive mouse events as input from the terminal.  To clear the screen, send ESC c (i.e. 0x33, 0x63) to the terminal.  To receive mouse events, follow [this document](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking).  I know it looks a bit complicated, let me try to find something better.

Comment: Here is a better explanation: [consol_codes(4)](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/4-console_codes/).

Comment: Note that to receive mouse events in real time, you first need to configure the terminal into uncooked or raw mode using termios.  This might be a bit annoying to do in assembly.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying ncurses. Please look at my edit.

Comment: @Greg Looks about right.  Make sure to read the documentation of ncurses carefully so you don't get caught by surprise.

Comment: x86-64 Linux system calls are made with `syscall`.  Terminal emulators handle cursor movement, you just make `read()` and `write()` system calls with escape sequences.  As fuz says, you probably want a library.  (I think even on a Linux console virtual terminal there aren't system calls for cursor movement.  You might be able to memory-map a screen buffer or something...)

Comment: `movq $msg1, %rdi` - you never want this.  Use `lea msg(%rip), %rdi` for position-independent code, otherwise use `mov $msg1, %edi` to optimize for position-dependent code.